# How to show progress when loading from Azure Storage tables?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, razor, azure-storage

The current solution I have at the moment is showing a spinner, but given that I have to load several thousand entries from an enormous table, it takes a long time to display, even for a small amount. Is there a way to show a progress bar in Razor when loading entries into the model from an Azure storage table?

Comment: Displaying thousands of items is bad UI . Querying Azure tables for thousands of items is also bad, they were not designed for that. Are you sure you want a solution for the wrong problem?

Comment: Yes. It's not great design but that's exactly what I want. The data is shown in an HTML table and is already able to be exported into CSV format.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the total count of objects to be retrieved and use that with the current number of asynchronously retrieved items to continually update a progress meter.

Comment: What if the total count of objects isn't known? The storage table is essentially a log table, I'm retrieving entries in order to dump into the View.

Comment: Are you sure there's no way to get the total number? If you have no idea how many total items there are how can you ever accurately represent how much progress you have made? You could have 1, 100 or 1000 more objects to load and have no idea. Maybe keep a count stored elsewhere and constantly update it based on transactions to the table. You could then use that, otherwise you're just guessing how much progress has been made or is left